# Как преобразовать метод в делегат

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия, делегаты

У меня есть метод:

```
public static Delegate MethodToDelegate(MethodInfo method)
{
    Delegate d = ...;
    // использовать ТОЛЬКО параметр method и d
    return d;
}
```

Как мне создать делегат `d` в этом методе. Я знаю, что можно использовать метод `CreateDelegate`, но как мне узнать тип делегата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParameterInfo[] pars = method.GetParameters();
        List<Type> param = new List<Type>();
        List<Type> methods = new List<Type>();
        methods.Add(method.ReturnType);
        foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars)
        {
            param.Add(p.ParameterType);
        }
        Delegate d = method.CreateDelegate(Expression.GetDelegateType(param.Union(methods).ToArray()));
        return d;
```

Но будьте внимательны передаваемый метод должен быть статическим, а так же не должен быть IsGenericMethod

Comment: Сложный путь...

Comment: @NewView А какой простой?

Comment: Это правильный способ, Павел, я бы сказал академический :) делайте так, это верный путь.

Comment: @NewView Я не понимаю вашей иронии? Вам не нравится способ передачи параметров?

Comment: Где вы увидели иронию? ничего подобного я в виду не имел.

Comment: @NewView "я бы сказал академический :) " - вот это. Может проясните тогда, что имели ввиду?

Comment: Способ "по учебнику", ничего плохого в этом я не вижу, я автору попытался ответить на его вопрос - а как проще :) Другими словами, попытался убедить что проще решения искать не надо.